# How to delete posts of user at delete account?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I just made a delete function of accounts, but I'm stuck on a problem.I need to also delete posts of user, at delete account.How can I make that? I have table `Users`, where I have all details from users, and table `Posts`, where also have `user_id` and `id`,`caption` and `image` of post.

**public function delete($id)**

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $profile = User::find($id);


        $profile->delete();
        Session::flash('remove', "The profile was successfully deleted!");
        return redirect('login');
    }
```

**Profile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function profileImage(){

        $imagePath = ($this->image) ?  $this->image : 'profile/vx2k9TEhkcgaRdOWKvs4lsxqOVmuzwumtwySEnvH.png';
        return '' . $imagePath;
    }

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function followers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);

    }


}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;


use App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Actuallymab\LaravelComment\CanComment;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'username', 'password',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->create([
                'title' => $user->username,
            ]);

        });
    }
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }



    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Post extends Model 
{
    protected $guarded = [];


    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }


}
```

**Migration posts table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Comment: [Eloquent model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) would work very well for this.

Comment: Can you help me a little with that please?I dont know how to use eloquents.I really appreciate if you give me some hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try to delete related model in the controller before the user, i.e.:

```
public function delete($id)
{
   $profile = User::find($id);
   $profile->posts()->delete();

   $profile->delete();
   Session::flash('remove', "The profile was successfully deleted!");
   return redirect('login');
}
```

Or you can go with model event, i.e.:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function ($user) {
        $user->profile()->create([
            'title' => $user->username,
        ]);

    });

    static::deleting(function($user) {
        $user->posts()->delete();
    });
}
```

Comment: please, for other's reference, accept the answer if you find it's correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, first public function works :) Can you tell me please, how can I protect this function to not be able used by normal users by direct link?Because I thinka some people can delete other users by typing the link ...

Comment: You can use authorization to protect a delete route, consider also that in laravel resourceful routes you have to use a form to call the delete method i's not a GET method, so is not an easy link click or typing.